# Take average of column values if strings in another column match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file made up of a list of filenames, their corresponding time stamp and the third value is the 'S' value.

Eg:

```
                            col1             col2       col3
hd75332_01dec15_int_Normal_001.s    2457358.61880    0.25426
hd75332_01dec15_int_Normal_002.s    2457358.62334    0.25590
hd75332_01dec15_int_Normal_003.s    2457358.62780    0.25178
hd75332_01dec15_int_Normal_004.s    2457358.63226    0.25287
hd75332_01feb07_int_Normal_001.s    2454133.55246    0.27092
hd75332_01feb07_int_Normal_002.s    2454133.55653    0.26926
hd75332_01feb07_int_Normal_003.s    2454133.56059    0.27149
hd75332_01feb07_int_Normal_004.s    2454133.56467    0.26733
hd75332_01nov17_int_Normal_001.s    2458059.56671    0.28945
hd75332_01nov17_int_Normal_002.s    2458059.57084    0.28566
hd75332_01nov17_int_Normal_003.s    2458059.57507    0.28170
hd75332_01nov17_int_Normal_004.s    2458059.57929    0.28075
```

There are sequences of 4 files where the filenames are exactly the same except for 001, 002, 003, 004. For each set of 4 similar filenames, I want to take an average of the time stamp and an average 'S' value. I want to generate a new file with the filename (minus the 001, 002, 003 or 004), the average time stamp and the average S value.

This is what I have tried:

```
inputs = pd.read_csv("LombScarInput.dat", header=None, delimiter=r"\s+", skiprows=1, names=["spectrafile", "HJD", "S"], dtype={"HJD":"float", "S":"float"})
S = inputs.S.values
HJD = inputs.HJD.values
spectrafile = inputs.spectrafile.values
data1 = df.groupby(df[spectrafile].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[0]).mean().reset_index()
```

I get the error message TypeError: object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

You can split by last `_` from right side by [`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html)and select first lists by `[0]` and pass to `groupby` with aggregation `mean`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['col1'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[0]).mean().reset_index()
```

Or if possible use slicing from remove last 6 values of filenames:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['col1'].str[:-6]).mean().reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df1)
                         col1          col2      col3
0  hd75332_01dec15_int_Normal  2.457359e+06  0.253702
1  hd75332_01feb07_int_Normal  2.454134e+06  0.269750
2  hd75332_01nov17_int_Normal  2.458060e+06  0.284390
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['col1'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[0])
0     hd75332_01dec15_int_Normal
1     hd75332_01dec15_int_Normal
2     hd75332_01dec15_int_Normal
3     hd75332_01dec15_int_Normal
4     hd75332_01feb07_int_Normal
5     hd75332_01feb07_int_Normal
6     hd75332_01feb07_int_Normal
7     hd75332_01feb07_int_Normal
8     hd75332_01nov17_int_Normal
9     hd75332_01nov17_int_Normal
10    hd75332_01nov17_int_Normal
11    hd75332_01nov17_int_Normal
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. I can't get this to work - I am very new to python. The original data is contained in a csv file names "LombScarInput.dat". Here is what I've written: 
`inputs = pd.read_csv("LombScarInput.dat", header=None, delimiter=r"\s+", skiprows=1, names=["spectrafile", "HJD", "S"], dtype={"HJD":"float", "S":"float"})`




`df1 = df.groupby(df['spectrafile'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[0]).mean().reset_index()`

Comment: @ebrown88 - Is file confidental? If not, can you send me file to my email from my profile?

Comment: sorry I can't figure out how to email. I have edited the original question with more information, I hope that helps. Thank you for your help.